# lastb: /var/log/btmp empty

Tags: linux, debian, logging

/var/log/btmp is the file that is supposed to contain all the bad login attempts (at least that was the case on Fedora). On my Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 server, it's empty. The permissions were originally:

`-rw-rw---- 1 root utmp 0 Jul  1 06:25 /var/log/btmp`

but I changed them to:

`-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jul  1 06:25 /var/log/btmp`

but that didn't work either. I'm still not seeing anything in btmp (and yes, I'm creating bad login attempts to test it).

I've Googled my brains out, but can't find a fix. Any ideas?

Comment: I confirm this behaviour on a fully patched debian lenny amd64 and i686. It works as expected on centos. Odd, did not notice this before. Time to open a bug, I suppose.

Comment: My CentOS machine does this, too. I have set `logrotate` to rotate it, and have a sizable `btmp.1`, although `btmp` is 0 bytes. `last -f btmp` yields nothing, though `last` and `last -f btmp.1` do. Very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a problem with openssh. I tested this on an Ubuntu system and bad ssh login attempts get logged to `/var/log/auth.log` but not to `btmp`. At the console, bad login attempts do go to `btmp`.

In Google searches, I'm seeing reports of this going back to 2006-2007.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear. But I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to try generating lots of different types of failed login attempts. Try from X (gdm or kdm or xdm), try from the console, try from ssh, try from sudo and try from su. Different subsystems can (and will) be configured different ways. It's not uncommon for ssh to be configured to use an internal login command that cuts around the /var/log/btmp business. Try the `last` command as well.

You might look in /var/log/secure to see if your failed login attempts are being stored there. But, I'm afraid I don't know the structure of the Debian log directory. Try `tail -f logfile` on anything in the /var/log directory. It's quite likely that ssh is logging something someplace.